Expected gain from coin flip with removing the pair of coins (HT) from the sequence.
The question is exactly the title of this post. Flip $N$ number 1 dollar coins. For every "exact" pair of (HT), it is removed from the table. We keep all the coins that remain on the table after the consecutive removal procedures, and the leftover coins from the table is the gain from this game. What is the expected gain of this game?
For instance, let's say N = 3. Then there are 8 possibilities: HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, TTT, THH, TTH, THT. If we reduce the sequence according to the problem, the eight of the above coin sequence will be: HHH, H, H, T, TTT, THH, TTH, T. Thus, EV when N = 3 is 2.
My initial approach is to note that tails at the very beginning of the sequence and heads at the end of the sequence cannot be removed by this procedure, and removing the first consecutive tails and last consecutive heads will give expected gain of 0 for the gain since the number of heads and tail flip that starts with H and ends with T will be identical. Another approach I was thinking of is to set indicator RV $X_{i} = 1$ if $i$th flip is H, and $(i+1)$th flip is T, and 0 else. Then the expected number of $HT$ sequence in the original flip is $\dfrac{1}{4} \times (N-1)$. Since the rest of coins can be likely to be in any of the spaces creaed by those sequence (e.g. If we define $Y_{i}$ to be the number of coins between $(i-1)$th HT and $i$th HT, by symmetricity, $Y_{i} = Y_{i+1}$), and observe that sequences at $Y_{i}$ and $Y_{i+1}$ cancels out.
However, I am not sure on how to proceed with those ideas, nor sure whether those approaches are flawless or not. Could anyone help with coming with the solution to this problem? Thanks!

I'd work recursively.  Let $E_n$ be the expected value for $n$ coins, so $E_1$ is $1$.  Then note that adding one more coin is equally likely to add $1$ or subtract it, with the one issue being, if the other coins were tied, the new one can only add $1$.

Note:  it's easy to work this out for any given (small) $N$.  It's just a binomial distribution.  Worth doing if for no other reason than that it will give you a lot of test cases you can use to check whatever you come up abstractly.

Clarification please: If you were to do four flips with result HHTT, would the score be $2$ or $0$?

If the result is HHTT, then the result will be 0 since HT can be removed twice in this sequence

Fix two integers $i$ and $j$ such that $1\le i<j\le n$. Let us find the probability that coins numbered $i$ and $j$ will be paired off in this process. In order for coins $i$ and $j$ to be paired off, it must be the case that coin $i$ is heads and coin $j$ is tails. Furthermore, all of the coins between $i$ and $j$ must pair off amongst themselves. Let us look at some examples to get a handle on this.

Suppose $i-j=1$, so the coins are adjacent. As long as coin $i$ is heads and coin $j$ is tails, then they will pair off, so the probability is $(1/2)^2$.

Suppose $i-j=2$, so there is one coin between. It is impossible for coin $i$ and $j$ to pair off. Furthermore, when $i-j$ is even, so there are an odd number of coins between, it is also impossible.

Suppose $i-j=3$, so two coins between. The probability that coins $i$ and $j$ pair off is $(1/2)^4=1/16$, because the only successful pattern is $\mathrm{H\,H\,T\,T}$.

Suppose $i-j=5$, with four coins between. The only ways that coins $i$ and $j$ can be paired together is if the pattern of six coins is either $\mathrm{H\,H\,H\,T\,T\,T}$ or  $\mathrm{H\,H\,T\,H\,T\,T}$, so the probability is $2\times (1/2)^6$.

Suppose $i-j=7$, with six coins between. There are now five patterns that allow coins $i$ and $j$ to pair off:$$
\mathrm{H\,H\,H\,H\,T\,T\,T\,T},\quad\\
\mathrm{H\,H\,H\,T\,H\,T\,T\,T},\quad\\
\mathrm{H\,H\,H\,T\,T\,H\,T\,T},\quad\\
\mathrm{H\,H\,T\,H\,H\,T\,T\,T},\quad\\
\mathrm{H\,H\,T\,H\,T\,H\,T\,T}.\quad
$$Therefore, the probability is $5\times (1/2)^{8}$.


So far, we have seen that when $i-j=2k+1$, with $2k$ coins between, the probability that coins $i$ and $j$ pair off is of the form $c_k\times (1/2)^{2k+2}$, where $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3)=(1,1,2,5)$. This is consistent with the Catalan numbers! Indeed, you can prove that rows of $2k$ coins which all pair off among themselves are exactly equivalent to Dyck paths of order $k$. That is, one can prove
$$
\mathbb P(\text{$i^\text{th}$ coin and $(i+2k+1)^\text{th}$ coin pair off})= C_k\times (1/2)^{2k+2},\\\text{where }\, C_k=\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}k.
$$
With this observation, the problem is almost solved. Define the indicator random variable $X_{i,j}$ to be $1$ if coins $i$ and $j$ pair off, and $0$ if not. The number of coins removed is equal to $2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^nX_{i,j}$ (because you remove two coins for each $(i,j)$ such that $X_{i,j}=1$). By linearity of expectation, and by the facts that $\mathbb E[X_{i,j}]=0$ when $i-j$ is even, while $\mathbb E[X_{i,i+2k+1}]=C_k\times (1/2)^{2k+2}$, we get that
$$
\mathbb E[\text{# coins removed}]=2\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-2)/2\rfloor} (n-2k-1)\cdot C_k\cdot (1/2)^{2k+2}.
$$
The expected number of coins remaining is $n-\mathbb E[\text{# coins removed}]$, so your question is fully answered.

Asymptotically, you can prove that the expected number of coins remaining is $2\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi}}$.
